# change context after the response in sent in django

Tags: python, django, web

I have a django view and I'm expecting some of the data in the context to change a few times a second. Can I load a new context into the template after the response is sent without sending a new request? Thanks.

**the view**

```
def debug(request):
    return render(request, 'all/debug.html', context={"x": x, "y": y})
```

**the template**

```
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="data"></canvas>
    <div class="graphing">
    <select class="graph-select"></select>
    <canvas id="graph" width="500"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    let y = "{{ y }}";
    let x = "{{ x }}"
    Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 0;
    var ctx = document.getElementById('graph').getContext('2d');
    var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
        // The type of chart we want to create
        type: 'line',

        // The data for our dataset
        data: {
            labels: x.split` `.map(n => +n),
            datasets: [{
                label: 'My First dataset',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                data: y.split` `.map(n => +n)
            }]
        },

        // Configuration options go here
        options: {
            responsive: false,
        }
    });

</script>
```

What I want is to dynamically change the x and y data without sending a new request

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49143909/is-it-possible-to-update-a-django-context-dictionary-without-reloading-the-page) answer your question?

Comment: @Sashaank Yes, it does. I was ultimately (after more work than anticipated) able to make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use ajax tech in your template.
[here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp) you can find some informations.

Answer (score 0):

just change the view to this
`

-

```
if somthing happens :
    return render(request, 'all/debug.html', context={"z": z, "t": t})
else:
    return render(request, 'all/debug.html', context={"x": x, "y": y})
return render(request, 'all/debug.html', context={"x": x, "y": y})
```

`

Comment: Yes, but I return it anyway. The problem is that I can't change the data *after* returning the response

Comment: @AdarMaori please describe where the response is going to is it from template to django views or the reverse